# SkiaSharp drawing image with GPU acceleration

Tags: xamarin.forms, gpu, skiasharp

I want to draw something with GPU acceleration in xamarin.forms. (and save the image later). When I call the following method the first time, I get an image and can show it in SKGLView. But when I call the method again, there is nothing (no error, too)

Can somebody give me a hint?

```
private SKImage CreateSKImage()
{
    SKImage sKImage;

    var glInterface = GRGlInterface.CreateNativeAngleInterface();
    var grContext = GRContext.Create(GRBackend.OpenGL, glInterface);            
    var surface = SKSurface.Create(grContext, true, new SKImageInfo(500, 500));            
    var canvas = surface.Canvas;

    var paintStroke = new SKPaint
    {
        IsAntialias = true,
        Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
        Color = SKColors.Purple,
        StrokeWidth = 1
    };

    canvas.DrawLine(new SKPoint(0, 0), new SKPoint(500, 500), paintStroke);

    surface.Canvas.Flush();

    sKImage = surface.Snapshot().ToRasterImage();          

    return sKImage;
}
```

edit: when I call the method from SKGLView onPaint,  then I get something. But when I call the method from anywhere else the *glInterface* is null ...hmmmm

How to create the OpenGL Interface the right way???

Comment: Make sure you're calling this on the main thread if you intend to use the opengl context that SKGLView is using.  OpenGL restricts each context to a particular thread and only one context can be active at time, SKGLView uses GLControl as a baseclass which handles context creation on the UI Thread.  Here's a resource for reading more about opengl contexts: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context